# C - Comparing numeric strings

Tags: c, strcmp, atoi, strtol

Out of professional curiosity, what is the safest / fastest / most efficient way to compare two fully numeric strings in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

char str1[5] = "123";
char str2[5] = "123";
char *ptr;

if(atoi(str1) == atoi(str2))
    printf("Equal strings");

if(strtol(str1,&ptr,10) == strtol(str2,&ptr,10))
    printf("Equal strings");

if(strcmp(str1,str2)==0)
    printf("Equal strings");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "comparison"? Your example contains only the `==` operator, but not `<`. Please give more examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strcmp ()` in my opinion, as it does not need any numeric conversions. But in this case you need to make sure that one of them stores a string which contains only numeric characters.

Also you can do `memcmp ()` on the string

**EDIT1**

As pointed out by others about the leading zeros, you can manually scan through the leading zeros and call `strcmp ()` or `memcmp ()` by passing a pointer to the first non-zero digit.

**EDIT2**

The below code tells what i am trying to say. This is only for integers, not for floating point numbers.

```
int main (void) {
  char s1[128], s2[128];
  char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;

  /* populate s1, s2 */

  while (*p1 && (*p1 == '0'))
    p1++;

  while (*p2 && (*p2 == '0'))
    p2++;

  if (strcmp (p1, p2) == 0)
    printf ("\nEqual");
  else
    printf ("\nNot equal");

  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

For floating point numbers, the trailing zeros after the decimal point should be chopped out manually.

Or do the whole stuff manually.

**EDIT4**

I would also like you to have a look at this code for floating point. This will detect leading zeros before the decimal and trailing zeros after the decimal. For example

`00000000000001.10000000000000` and `1.1` will be `Equal` for the below code

```
int main (void) {
  char s1[128], s2[128];
  char *p1, *p2, *p1b, *p2b;

  printf ("\nEnter 1: ");
  scanf ("%s", s1);
  printf ("\nEnter 2: ");
  scanf ("%s", s2);

  p1 = s1;
  p2 = s2;
  /* used for counting backwards to trim trailing zeros
   * in case of floating point
   */
  p1b = s1 + strlen (s1) - 1;
  p2b = s2 + strlen (s2) - 1;


  /* Eliminate Leading Zeros */
  while (*p1 && (*p1 == '0'))
    p1++;

  while (*p2 && (*p2 == '0'))
    p2++;

  /* Match upto decimal point */
  while (((*p1 && *p2) && ((*p1 != '.') && (*p2 != '.'))) && (*p1 == *p2))
  {
    p1++;
    p2++;
  }

  /* if a decimal point was found, then eliminate trailing zeros */
  if ((*p1 == '.') && (*p2 == '.'))
  {
    /* Eliminate trailing zeros (from back) */
    while (*p1b == '0')
      p1b--;
    while (*p2b == '0')
      p2b--;

    /* match string forward, only upto the remaining portion after
     * discarding of the trailing zero after decimal
     */
    while (((p1 != p1b) && (p2 != p2b)) && (*p1 == *p2))
    {
      p1++;
      p2++;
    }
  }

  /* First condition on the LHS of || will be true for decimal portion
   * for float the RHS will be . If not equal then none will be equal
   */
  if (((*p1 == '\0') && (*p2 == '\0')) ||  ((p1 == p1b) && (p2 == p2b)))
    printf ("\nEqual");
  else
    printf ("\nNot equal");

  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Needs some testing before use.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the method I always use, as I rely on the str* family of functions a lot.  Looks like it's actually the norm.  Good to know!

Comment: @Valdogg21: have a look at the code i updated, this now can compare floating point numbers, as per the protocol you have set.

Answer (score 4):

`str(n)cmp` is the fastest and safest.

Comment: `str(n)cmp` fails on integer strings with a differing number of leading zeros.

Comment: @JAB: are you saying that the strings "002" and "0002" are the same?

Comment: @cnicutar: What are you talking about? I was referring to a situation such as comparing `100` and `0100`. The comparison will fail because both `strcmp` and `strncmp` would return non-zero values when the desired value would be 0, indicating equality.

Comment: @Chris: No, I'm saying that the numbers represented by the strings "002" and "0002" are the same.

Comment: I thought you were thinking of something else :-) Indeed, I wasn't thinking about leading zeros.

Comment: @JAB: I sure hope you're talking about the bit values, because the strings "100" and "0100" are emphatically NOT the same.

Comment: These are string comparisons, not numeric. I mean I see in his example that it's "123", but these are still string operations.

Comment: @Chris: Note the part saying "two fully numeric strings".

Comment: @JAB: D'oh. See figure of foot in mouth for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for them to be idential, `strncmp` will be the fastest and safest since it can do a direct comparison without any conversions.  It is also generally considered safer than `strcmp`.

However, if you want `00` and `0` to be equal, or other ways that you can represent the same number slightly differently, you will need to use `atoi`.

Comment: "The atoi() function has been deprecated by strtol() and should not be used in new code."

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the "safest" way would likely be to convert both arguments to integers and then test, as that way you'll avoid the potential leading-zeros problem. It's probably not the fastest or most efficient method, though.

Comment: To do this correctly, you would need an arbitrary-size integer type, which is not available in standard C.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use following :

if(strcmp("123","123") == 0)

{

```
  printf("The strings are equal");
```

}

else

{

```
  printf("The strings are not equal.");
```

}

In my opinion it should work.

Comment: the asker wanted to match if the two numbers represented in the string was equal or not

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this way for integers:

```
int strcmp_for_integers(char *aa, char *bb){
    char aa2[11] = "";
    char bb2[11] = "";
    int answer;

    sprintf(aa2, "%010d", atoi(aa));
    sprintf(bb2, "%010d", atoi(bb));
    answer = strcmp(aa2, bb2);

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: `atoi` is deprecated