# (C) Get safe int input

Tags: c

So I tasked myself to write a function, that:

1. overwrites an int with a safe value (not return gibberish if the
   user decides to input char-s or anything bigger by absolute value
   than (2^31-1)
2. if input exceeds (2^31 - 1) (meaning if the user inputs 8 or more
   digits) the int must be overwritten with the upper value

Here is the code:

```
void getSafeIntWithBoundaries(int *dest, int lo, int hi, const char *message);
bool anyChars(const char *input, int len);

int main() {
    int x;
    getSafeIntWithBoundaries(&x, 1, 10, "Enter an integer between 0 and 10.");
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

void getSafeIntWithBoundaries(int * dest, int lo, int hi, const char * message) {
    char input[33];
    while (1) {
        puts(message);
        fgets(input, 33, stdin);
        int len = strlen(input);
        if (input[len - 1] == '\n') { input[len - 1] = '\0'; }
        --len;
        if (bool reset = anyChars(input, len)) {
            puts("Try again.");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            int ret;
            if (strcmp("2147483648", input) < 0) {
                *dest = hi;
                return;
            }
            sscanf(input, "%d", &ret);
            ret = ret > hi ? hi : ret;
            ret = ret < lo ? lo : ret;
            *dest = ret;
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool anyChars(const char * input, int len) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(input[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A few more notes:

- in `getSafeIntWithBoundaries(...)` I'm getting rid of the `'\n'`, I'm
  changing it for a `'\0'`, respectively decreasing `int len;` which holds
  the length of the input.
- `anyChars()` checks whether the input contains any non digit `char`. If
  it does, then the user has to re-enter. **One of the problems is
  however that in case of failure, message needs to be printed out only
  once. If I input something ridiculously long, message will be printed
  multiple times.** I don't know how to fix this.
- the strcmp() bit checks if the user entered a number bigger than
  (2^31 - 1). If the user has, then the int must be overwritten with
  the high value and the function needs to end. ***Problem is however, if
  the user enters a very long number, the target int will be
  overwritten with the low boundary.*** I don't know how to fix that
  either.
- 2 ?s making sure the target int won't exceed its boundaries. I marked
  the parts that I can't figure out with bold, essentially that's the
  whole question.

  Suggestions on improving the code are welcomed as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The stuff marked in bold.

Comment: If each of that is a question then please focus on a single question. But in fact none of that seems a question. The whole post is more of a list of requirements which you want to have matched. Again, what single specific programming related question do you have? What is the one thing you want to change about your code? How does the code you show not act as desired?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be C.

Comment: Well what does it seem like, @EOF?

Comment: @SergeyTeryan I don't know, maybe C++? It certainly *is not* valid C.

Comment: @Yunnosch Everything is described clearly, I don't think there's anything left that's unclear. Also, this question doesn't have to be about 1 single issue, at least according to the rules.

Comment: @EOF Which part of my code isn't valid C?

Comment: @xing what is the issue with `strcmp` and `sscanf`?

Comment: @SergeyTeryan `if (bool reset = anyChars(input, len))` is not valid C.

Comment: @EOF No, it is. I'm assigning `reset` the result of the function and then compare it whether it's  `true`.

Comment: @SergeyTeryan \*sigh\*, no, C does not allow declarations in `if()` statements.

Comment: @EOF *nods* you're correct, thanks for the lesson in pedantism

Comment: @SergeyTeryan Given how sloppy, unorganized and confused your code is, you could *really* do with a lot *more* pedantism. If you can't even follow the basic rules of the language, how are you ever going to fix your sloppy thinking, the likes of which lead you to do a lexical string comparison in order to compare numbers represented by variable-length strings.

Comment: @EOF In case you didn't notice, the code was unfinished. The idea is to get it to work first, then optimize it second. Rules aren't always worthwhile, especially in a language like C. As for comparing numbers in the form of a string, a few people agree this isn't such a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6389959/10692664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suggestions on improving the code are welcomed

Code fails many cases

---

**Overflow UB**

When the range exceed `int`, `sscanf(input, "%d", &ret)` is undefined behavior.

**Long lines not consumed**

When input is more than 32 characters (including the `'\n`), left over input remains.

**Null character input**

Input starting with a *null character* `'\0'` lead to undefined behavior with  `input[len - 1]`

**Non ASCII input**

`isdigit(input[i])` is undefined behavior when `input[i] < 0`.

**Assumed ranged**

Code uses `int` assuming it covers the range `2^31 - 1`.  C requires `int` to have a 
minimum range of [-32,767 ... 32,767].

**Unclear goals**

"if input exceeds (2^31 - 1) (meaning if the user inputs 8 or more digits)" --> What if input is `"0000000000000000000000000000000000001\n"?   35 zeros?  It is in range yet exceeds 8 digits and exceed 33 character buffer.

**End-of-file**

`puts("Try again.");` does not make sense if input is closed.  I'd expect `int getSafeIntWithBoundaries()` to return 1 on success, 0 on failure, `EOF` on end-of-file/input error.

---

Below is some untested code - will test later.  I'll work on the *message* details later.  It is certainty more than what one might think is needed to simply read an `int, but if you want robust code, it is work.

To read an entire *line* of input obliges reading until `'\n'` or `EOF`.

I'd tolerate leading and trailing spaces.

`strtol()` is good , but then the entire line needs to be read first.   Recall valid input can have many leading spaces or zeros.

Do not overflow `int`math`- it is UB.  Summing the value with negatives`int` has greater range than the positive side.

Pre-C99 `/,%` has implementation defined behavior when the remainder is non-zero - so I avoided that.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT_MIN_LS_DIGIT ((-(INT_MIN + 10)) % 10)
#define INT_MIN_DIV_10 ((INT_MIN + INT_MIN_LS_DIGIT)/10)

int getSafeIntWithBoundaries(int * dest, int lo, int hi, const char *message) {
  fputs(message, stdout);
  fflush(stdout);  // Insure data to sent out completely

  int ch;
  while (isspace((ch = fgetc(stdin))) && (ch != '\n')) {
    ;
  }
  bool positive = true;
  if (ch == '-' || ch == '+') {
    positive = ch == '+';
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
  }

  bool digit_found = false;
  bool overflow = false;

  int sum = 0;
  while (isdigit(ch)) {
    digit_found = true;
    int digit = ch = '0';
    // Detect possible overflow
    if (sum <= INT_MIN_DIV_10
        && (sum < INT_MIN_DIV_10 || digit > INT_MIN_LS_DIGIT)) {
      sum = INT_MIN;
      overflow = true;
    } else {
      sum = sum * 10 - digit;
    }
  }

  if (positive) {
    if (sum < -INT_MAX) {
      sum = INT_MAX;
      overflow = true;
    } else {
      sum = -sum;
    }
  }

  if (sum > hi) {
    sum = hi;
    overflow = true;
  }
  if (sum < lo) {
    sum = lo;
    overflow = true;
  }

  *dest = sum;

  while (isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
  }

  if (ch == EOF && iserror(stdin)) {
    return EOF; // Rare input error detected
  }

  if (!digit_found) {
    return 1; // or a "No digit found" error code
  }

  if (overflow) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return 1; // or a "Overflow" error code
  }

   if (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    return 1; // or a "Extra trailing junk" error code
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtol` could be used to parse an integer from a string. It provides for overflow and the pointer to the last character allows for testing for valid terminating characters. This set the range to 0 and INT_MAX but any range from INT_MIN to INT_MAX could be used. The terminating character is nul but could be comma, semicolon or any appropriate character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

//inputs
// char *line : pointer to text to be parsed
// char **next : pointer to pointer to allow modification of caller's pointer
// char *term : pointer to characters to be considered terminators
// int *value : pointer to int to allow modification of caller's int
// int min : minimum value of range
// int max : maximum value of range
// returns : 0 failure or 1 success
int get_int_range ( char *line, char **next, char *delim, int *value, int min, int max)
{
    long int input = 0;
    char *end = NULL;//will point to end of parsed value

    if ( line == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    errno = 0;
    input = strtol ( line, &end, 10);//get the integer from the line. end will point to the end of the parsed value
    if ( end == line) {// nothing was parsed. no digits
        printf ( "input [%s] MUST be a number\n", line);
        return 0;// return failure
    }
    // *end is the character that end points to
    if ( *end != '\0' && !( delim && strchr ( delim, *end))) {// is *end '\0' or is *end in the set of term characters
        printf ( "problem with input: [%s] \n", line);
        return 0;
    }
    if ( ( errno == ERANGE && ( input == LONG_MAX || input == LONG_MIN))
    || ( errno != 0 && input == 0)){// parsing error from strtol
        perror ( "input");
        return 0;
    }
    if ( input < min || input > max) {// parsed value is outside of range
        printf ( "input out of range %d to %d\n", min, max);
        return 0;
    }

    if ( next != NULL) {// if next is NULL, caller did not want pointer to end of parsed value
        *next = end;// *next allows modification to caller's pointer
    }
    if ( value == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    *value = input;// *value allows modification to callers int
    return 1;// success
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[900] = {'\0'};
    int valid = 0;
    int number = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "Enter number or enter quit\n");
        fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);//read a line
        if ( strcmp ( line, "quit\n") == 0) {
            return 1;// if quit is entered, exit the program
        }
        line[strcspn ( line, "\n")] = '\0';//remove trailing newline
        valid = get_int_range ( line, NULL, "", &number, 0, INT_MAX);// call to parse a value
    } while ( !valid);// on failure, keep looping the above

    printf ( "input is %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```